# DSolve returns a Solve expression

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I want to solve the differential equation $\frac{g'(x)g''(x)-g(x)g'''(x)}{xg'''(x)+2g''(x)}=B$, with $B$ an arbitrary constant, so I entered the following into Mathematica:

```
DSolve[(g'[x]*g''[x] - g[x]*g'''[x])/(x*g'''[x] + 2*g''[x]) == B, g[x], x]
```

But this returns a solution which is a coupled Solve expression for $g(x)$ and a new constant K$5705:

$\text{Solve}\left[\left\{x=\int \frac{\frac{(2 \text{K$\$$5705}-B) \exp \left(-\frac{3 B \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{B}{\sqrt{4 c_1-B^2}}-\frac{2 \text{K$\$$5705}}{\sqrt{4 c_1-B^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{4 c_1-B^2}}-c_2\right)}{2 \sqrt{-B \text{K$\$$5705}+c_1+\text{K$\$$5705}^2}}+\frac{6 B \sqrt{-B \text{K$\$$5705}+c_1+\text{K$\$$5705}^2} \exp \left(-\frac{3 B \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{B}{\sqrt{4 c_1-B^2}}-\frac{2 \text{K$\$$5705}}{\sqrt{4 c_1-B^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{4 c_1-B^2}}-c_2\right)}{\left(4 c_1-B^2\right) \left(\left(\frac{B}{\sqrt{4 c_1-B^2}}-\frac{2 \text{K$\$$5705}}{\sqrt{4 c_1-B^2}}\right){}^2+1\right)}}{B+\text{K$\$$5705}} \, d\text{K$\$$5705}+c_3,g(x)=\sqrt{-B \text{K$\$$5705}+c_1+\text{K$\$$5705}^2} \exp \left(-\frac{3 B \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{B}{\sqrt{4 c_1-B^2}}-\frac{2 \text{K$\$$5705}}{\sqrt{4 c_1-B^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{4 c_1-B^2}}-c_2\right)-B x\right\},\{g(x),\text{K$\$$5705}\}\right]$

I don't understand this solution; why does it solve for $K$ and $g(x)$ when I'm just looking for $g(x)$ for any $x$?

Comment: It is not solving for `x`. It is actually solving for `g[x]`. The result is in fact `Solve[{x == expression1, g[x] == expression2}, {g[x], K$174204}]`, which indicates that it is trying to solve for `g[x]` and `K`. `Solve` probably doesn't know how to solve that equation explicitly (if it is even possible).

Comment: Part of the problem is an unevaluated integral, with which one could eliminate the K variable (note K is a function of `x`, not a constant).  This is the best *M* could do with your problem.  That's not to say there isn't a way to get it unstuck, but it might take considerable cleverness (or it might not be possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, there is a minor bug, in that it shouldn't be returning temporary variables lik `K$174204` but the standard `K[1]`, ...  I've reported this to the relevant developer.

Note, however, that if `Solve` did know how to solve the equations, it would return a rule `g[x]->expr`, just like `DSolve` wants to return.  So on some level, this answer is correct.  This point is the 4th bullet point of the details of ref/DSolve, which also has a link to an example illustrating it.

By comparison, `DSolveValue` returns unevalated for this input, precisely because it can't construct an explicit expression for `g[x]` to return.